# Hotcakes ProductViewer - only show related items if explicitly defined

Tags: e-commerce

In the Hotcakes Commerce ProductViewer, my goal is to only show related products if they have been explicitly defined via Hotcakes Administration > edit Product > Related Items. In other words, I do not want to show related items inferred/learned by Hotcakes from customer purchase history. What is the best way to achieve that?

In Views\Products\Index.cshtml, we have access to the ProductPageViewModel which includes RelatedItems. However, RelatedItems is a list of SingleProductViewModels, which don't seem to provide any way of differentiating explicitly from implicitly defined related items. We also have access to LocalProduct (that is, the current Product itself), however I don't see anything about related items in the Product object. What is the best way to access this information?

Alternately, is there an option in Hotcakes to simply turn off learning of related options (and thus only use those that are explicitly defined)? That would be even better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a great question, and the first time I've heard it.  Unfortunately, Hotcakes doesn't allow you to do that, even through the API.  There's also not a setting to turn this off.  This feature is intended to be a time-saving automation feature that does literally automatically relate products in a data-driven way, based upon customer behavior.  That is, in addition to any manual product associations you make.  Unfortunately, due to how this is automated, I'm not even sure there's a reliable way to do this using the API.

I'm sorry that I don't have a better answer for you.  It's quite rare that I ever say that Hotcakes can't do something that a person asks to do.  There's usually always a way to get a desired functionality done.

**Background:**

Products can be associated manually (the old-fashioned way) by going into the product administration and manually looking up other products to associate with the product being edited.  Once the choice is saved, the products are now an upsell on their respective product details pages.

Products that are automatically associated are done so at the point of checkout completion.  So if John Dough buys a t-shirt with a hat and they weren't associated with each other before, they are once his checkout is completed.  At the API level, there's no distinction between whether this was done manually or automatically.  They're the same.

Comment: Got it, thanks Will. Is the API the only way to un-relate products? We have a number of irrelevant product relationships that were established during our internal testing, and now we are preparing to launch the store for customers. So it looks like I'll need to either get rid of those associations or hide all display of related products.

Comment: You can change the product relationships by editing each product.  You can also delete all of the test data in the "Superuser Admin" area in the store administration.

Comment: When editing a product in the store administration, I don't see the implicitly learned relationships listed (only those that we have set explicitly). Also, on the "Superuser Admin" page, I don't have the "Clear Store Data" options; I am guessing that is because I'm using version 1.10.4 Pro. Is there perhaps a database way to achieve removal of a relationship? I looked through the hcc_* tables and wasn't able to find where the product relations live. I see table hcc_ProductRelationships, however it has zero rows even though we may numerous explicitly set and implicitly learned relationships.

Comment: Note that a workaround for me has been cloning the affected products and then deleting the originals. That worked well enough.

Comment: @AdamBernstein Thank you for the follow-up comments.  It sounds like your chosen workaround is actually a pretty good way to make this happen.  Thanks for noting it.